# Server DateTime issue -> client get bad experience

Tags: asp.net

If server is located in US and website user is from Asia, when user add a new comment, he sees that the comment is added 10 hours ago because there is 10 hours timing difference in Asia and US.

What I want to do is when displaying comment, automatically convert date time to the time of target country or region where user come from.

- Track user region/country
- DateTime in any webpage should be converted to that country time

So that I can display user that he posted comment a few second ago...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Handle all dates internally as [UTC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx),
   meaning 0 hour offset
2. Use the language/country part of the user-agent string or the ip address to detect where the user is from, and look up the timezone.
3. Use [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382835.aspx)..) to convert the UAC time to the users local time

Point 2 will be the most work unless you find some lookup table or existing code to do this.

Comment: http://ipaddressextensions.codeplex.com/ - may be useful for tracking country name....

Comment: http://onlineaspect.com/examples/timezone/index.html -> tracks timeZone with javascript....Now its much easy for me to detect/convert dateTime..